# How to go to a directory that has spaces in its name?

Tags: macos, mac

I am beginner to the Mac command line interface.

For example I want to go to directory "how are you".

But when I type `cd how are you`, it is avoided. When I change the name to be without space,
`howareyou` to the directory, it works. Any help?

And also how to create an [AppleScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppleScript) script
to go to particular a directory?

Comment: Should be on superuser.com

Comment: @senthilmuthu, after using the same OpenID here at superuser.com, you can associate your accounts at http://stackoverflow.com/users/141302?tab=accounts

Comment: Spaces - the final frontier!  http://superuser.com/questions/29111/if-spaces-in-filenames-are-possible-why-do-some-of-us-still-avoid-using-them

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
cd 'how are you'
```

Or,

```
cd how\ are\ you
```

Comment: You are welcome. Try: http://www.google.com/search?q=applescript+tutorial

Comment: hi i want to go to
cd \Desktop\senthilmuthu\SenthilmuthuSoftwares\check
this says no directory...any help

Comment: This is not \ but / This is not /Desktop/... but ~/Desktop/...

Comment: Does the standard Unix way of typing %20 instead of space also work?

Comment: @bert, using %20 is *not* a standard Unix way. That is "percent-encoding", as used in URLs: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

Answer (score 2):

And to avoid problems, use Tab to automatically complete the name for you. Like if you have three directories in your home folder, `~/`:

- "`how are you`"
- "`how are we`"
- "`how is she`"

Then:

- type "`cd ~/h`", press Tab; this yields "`cd ~/how\`" and a beep, telling you there's more
- optionally: press Tab again, to see the list of matching names
- next, type "`a`", press Tab; this yields "`cd ~/how\ are\`" and a beep
- optionally: press Tab again, to see the list of matching names
- next, type "`y`", press Tab; this yields "`cd ~/how\ are\ you/`"

(Funny: the rendering of the backtick is slightly different in text and in lists. Favouring lists then...)

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want an AppleScript to change it's current working directory, it isn't possible for the entire script as `do shell script` "uses a new shell process, so state such as changes to variables and the working directory is not saved from one to the next." ([Source](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/technotes/tn2002/tn2065.html))

```
do shell script 'cd /PATH/TO/DIRECTORY/; more commands here'
```

If you want to use AppleScript to open up and change to the directory in Terminal:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    do script "cd /PATH/TO/DIRECTORY"
end tell
```

Comment: I doubt the first really changes the working directory of the AppleScript? 
`osascript -e 'do shell script "cd ~/Desktop/"' -e 'do shell script "pwd"'` (That second example works fine though; `osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal"' -e 'activate' -e 'do script "cd /PATH/TO/DIRECTORY"' -e 'end tell'`)

Comment: @Arjan van Bentem - I've added some clarification and a correction. Thanks!