# Attempting to open AppData with Win + R and %appdata% but doesn't work

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, run-dialog, appdata

I have a laptop, specifically an Asus R540L, where I'm facing an issue when trying to open the AppData folder using the <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> shortcut and inserting `%appdata%`. Instead of opening the folder, it displays the "Which application do you want to use to open this file?" screen, prompting me to select a program:

[image: Win+R; %appdata%]

[image: With which application do you want to open the file?]

It tries to open a text-file with the following content:

> Starting PC Finder Deinstallation ...
>
> Missing pc finder deinstaller ... Delete C:\Users\Asus
> R540L\Desktop\CATEGORIZE-NOTEBOOK.bat ... End ...

The folder under `User\AppData\Roaming` does exist, and I can access it manually through Windows Explorer. However, the <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> method I described earlier doesn't work.

Do you have any ideas on how to resolve this issue?

P.S.: I am unable to perform a clean installation of Windows, so I would like to find a solution within the current system without reinstalling. It's also important to note that the "Which application do you want to use to open this file?" screen appears every time I start up the laptop.

Comment: Works fine here (Windows 11 Pro).  Have you enabled Hidden files and folders?  Works in Windows 10 Pro as well.

Comment: @John I did indeed. Also when I disable the function; same error.

Comment: What's shown in cmd.exe output if you do `echo %APPDATA%`?

Comment: Your system has a lot of issues.  The fact you get this prompt, every time you start your laptop, is a sign you should perform an in-place reinstall of Windows.  Does your username by chance contain a space in it? If you use `%windir%` instead of `%appdata%` does it work?

Comment: @John Yes, it does. The User-Name is "Asus R540L"; Is this not good? When I try to change it in control panel it wouldn't change the name of the User-folder, wouldn't it?

Comment: I agree - something wrong with the OS.

Comment: @PeterAndres - Try running "%appdata%" with the quotes, if that works, the problem is the username not your installation.

Comment: Thanks y'all for helping me out, but; I found the reason for the problem. Very strange but there was a file named "Asus" saved under C:\Users containg the message i wrote in my question. I deleted it immediately - et voilà: Now the AppData-Folder opens right away when I attempt to open it via Win + R-Method. Also: The prompt doesn't show up anymmore at start-up. Thanks again everyone for helping.

Comment: @PeterAndres it's definitely not recommended. You can get around it with quotes as shown above, but if some program handles that incorrectly, you're risking some issues. See e.g. https://superuser.com/questions/29111/what-technical-reasons-exist-for-not-using-space-characters-in-file-names - it's about regular file names, but it's even worse when talking about a crucial system directory.

Comment: @PeterAndres - Submit a detailed answer instead of using a temporary comment.

Comment: @Ramhound I did. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @Destroy666 Thanks for clearifying, but; how am I able to change the name of my user-folder without riscing to "destroy" (?) my user?

Comment: There is a way but it involves a lot of manual steps and potential problems  if the system is heavily set up, since Windows doesn't provide an easy way of renaming that... You'll need to mess with registry and bunch of app config files if you want to do it 100% properly. But that's unrelated to the initial question.

Answer (score 0):

There was a file named "Asus" saved under C:\Users containg the message i wrote in my question. I deleted it immediately - et voilà: Now the AppData-Folder opens right away when I attempt to open it via Win + R-method.

The prompt doesn't show up anymore at start-up.